# Replace column names with single line of code

Tags: r

Data frame with 4 columns and want to replace 2nd and 3rd column names only.

```
data frame=df
col.names =A,B,C,D
New col.names= Z,F
```

i have tried with the below code :

```
colnames(df)[2]<-"Z"
colnames(df)[3]<-"F"
```

but is there any possibility to rename with single line of code ?
Actual data frame contains 150+ colnames, so searching for better solution.

Comment: google: `"rename multiple columns in r"`

Answer (score 3):

As it is a `data.frame`, `names` can also work in place of `colnames` as `names` of a `data.frame` is the column names.  Subset the column names with index `[2:3]` (if it is a range of columns or use `[c(2, 3)]`) and assign it to the new column names by concatenating (`c`) names as a `vector`

```
names(df)[2:3] <- c("Z", "F")
```